# Date zero for Firebird date and timestamp data type

Tags: delphi, firebird

What date is considered date zero for Firebird's date and timestamp datatypes? The documentation on the firebird.org website says 11/17/1898.  When I connect to a FB 3.0 database using MS Access and the FB ODBC driver, fields with time only data show date zero as 11/30/1899.  That same data shows as 12/30/1899 in a Delphi program (inspecting it in the debugger).

Comment: Are you by chance in a country that has not yet adopted the Gregorian Calendar?

Comment: I think this discrepancy is probably because both 11/17/1898 and and 11/30/1899 are before 12/30/1899, which is Delphi's "day zero" for dates, and the Delphi RTL doesn't entertain negative day-numbers for dates.

Comment: I don't know the answer about Firebird, but for the Delphi tDateTime type, zero represents 1899-12-30.  The Delphi RTL has no problem with "negative day numbers", and handles dates in the range 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31.

Comment: No.  I am in the USA.

Comment: ODBC uses the OLE/ActiveX value for a zero date, IIRC, which would be 12/30/1899. The same value is used in Access and Excel for a zero date.

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this question, I used the debugger in IBExpert to examine a timestamp field containing only a time value.  It shows the date as 12/30/1899.  This sugguests there may be a bug in the current Firebird ODBC driver (or the way Access interprets the data) and that the Firebird online documentation is inaccurate in this instance.